# Where can I get older versions of the Flash Player Debugger?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, debugging

Abobe seems to only list the most recent debugger version, even though I can target previous players in build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find older players here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html